# How to create Item Templates that add more than one file?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-generation, itemtemplate

I've created an Item Template for VS2008, per these [instructions](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/visual-studio-how-to-create-item-templates) and it seems simple enough.  However, is it possible to add more than one file to the project?

For instance, let's say I create a AcmeWidget Item Template.  When I select it in VS2008, I'd like it to create an AcmeScreen winForm and a AcmeScreenSetup winform.

Is this possible with the Item Template paradigm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to add more than one item. I think to add more than one item you will need to create a new Visual Studio project template.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski